# Ranking functions from a given number in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as Rank,
SalesAmount  
from
    dbo.FactInternetSales
```

This will give you:

```
          Rank,      SalesAmount  
          1,         3578.27
          2,         3399.99 
          3,         3399.99
          4,         699.0982
          5,         799.0982
```

but I want to get like this: skip up to the number I pass `@skipnum` (e.g. 10)

```
          Rank,       SalesAmount  
          11,         3578.27
          12,         3399.99 
          13,         3399.99
          14,         699.0982
          15,         799.0982
```

Is there anyway in SQL Server 2008 to get like this using ranking functions not cursors?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) + @skipnum AS [Rank], ...
```

However why are you using `SELECT 1` to indicate rank? Shouldn't rank actually be meaningful, e.g. `ORDER BY SalesAmount DESC`? Also if you expect them to come back 11, 12, 13... you should add an outer `ORDER BY`...

Answer (score 2):

Just add @skipnum to the function

```
select 
    row_number() over (order by (select 1)) + @skipnum as Rank,
    SalesAmount  
from
    dbo.FactInternetSales
```

The `OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))` means a *arbitrary order* so I hope it's just for the question...

Comment: Perhaps not "random"? More like unknown order. It can't be used to get a random row like using 'order by newid()'.

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: changed to "arbitrary" which is more correct

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    @skipnum + row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as Rank,
    SalesAmount  
from
    dbo.FactInternetSales
```